# to view pdf and images(jpg,gif,tiff,png) in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf

I have a requirement to build an anuglar js app where a user can view respective files. Files format will be pdf ang images (gif,png,jog,tiff,efx). I am wondering if there is any angular directive available for this. If not is it possible to build such viewer in angular app.

Also i want to ask if ngembed can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are two many PDF viewer in Angular , you can implement by looking at respective samples.

[Viewer 1](https://github.com/winkerVSbecks/angular-pdf-viewer)

[viewer 2](https://github.com/sayanee/angularjs-pdf)

Comment: i have done pdf viewer i want to show any file irrespective of its extension on a page.